# Undefined Variable in Blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this in my controller:

```
public function detail($id) {
    $data = DB::table('data_api')->where('id', $id)->get();
    $carousel = DB::table('data_carousel')->where('data_api_id', $id)->get();
    return view('detail', ['data_api' => $data]);
    return view('detail', ['data_carousel' => $carousel]);
}
```

But when I try to echo-ing, `$carousel` by `{{ $carousel }}`, it says not found. But `$data` work perfectly. Any idea?

> Undefined variable: carousel (View:
>   /mylaravelproject/resources/views/detail.blade.php)

Comment: try `{{$data_carousel}}`

Comment: Still same, "Undefined variable: data_carousel (View: /mylaravelproject/resources/views/detail.blade.php)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change the double return statement to a single return

```
return view('detail', ['data_api' => $data]);
return view('detail', ['data_carousel' => $carousel]);
```

to

```
return view('detail', ['data_api' => $data, 'data_carousel' => $carousel]);
```

Comment: Solved with `return view('detail', ['data_api' => $data, 'data_carousel' => $carousel]);` and `{{ $data_carousel }}`. Thanksss

Answer (score 1):

you returning view two times that's why only `$data_api` is available in view,

try this

```
public function detail($id) {
    $data = DB::table('data_api')->where('id', $id)->get();
    $carousel = DB::table('data_carousel')->where('data_api_id', $id)->get();

    return view('detail', ['data_api' => $data, 'data_carousel' => $carousel]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

```
public function detail($id) {
    $data = DB::table('data_api')->where('id', $id)->get();
    $carousel = DB::table('data_carousel')->where('data_api_id', $id)->get();
    return view('detail', ['data_carousel' => $carousel,'data_api' => $data]);
}
```

You are returning two views from the same controller. After the first `return` execution of code is halt and it will not `return` the second view. That's why you are unable to get the second view parameters

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return two times from a function and expect both to actually return something. After the first `return`, execution of the function is stopped.

Try returning both variables at once instead:

```
return view('detail', [
    'data_api' => $api,
    'data_carousel' => $carousel
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with following:

```
public function detail($id) {
    $data = DB::table('data_api')->where('id', $id)->get();
    $carousel = DB::table('data_carousel')->where('data_api_id', $id)->get();
    return view('detail')->with('data_api', $data)->with('data_carousel', $carousel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return view like below

```
public function detail($id) {
    $data = DB::table('data_api')->where('id', $id)->get();
    $carousel = DB::table('data_carousel')->where('data_api_id', $id)->get();
    return view('detail', compact('data','carousel'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am curious about the difference in return view that I use, and `compact()` that you recommend (I have used it several times but i doesn't really understand). Are there references to this?

Comment: @abaykan The `compact()` function creates an array from variables and their values. and their syntax like this `compact(var1,var2...)`

Answer (score 0):

is that really working now? You tell us you are getting

`Undefined variable: carousel (View: /mylaravelproject/resources/views/detail.blade.php)`

And you will get that because you are not passing the variable carousel to your view, you are naming your variables as `data_api` and `data_carousell`

Second, you should pass your variables as an asociative array in only one sentence not two view calls like this

```
return view('detail', ['carousel' => $carousel,'data' => $data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i use

```
@if(isset($users))
```

before my foreach like this example:

```
                <div class="form-group" id="boardAdminUserIdCon">
                    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></span> مدیر بورد</p>
                    <select name="boardAdminUserId" id="boardAdminUserId" class="form-control" required="required">
                        <option value="">{{ __('auth.CHOOSEYOURADMIN') }}...</option>
                             @if(isset($users))
                                  @foreach($users as $user)
                                        <option value="{{ $user['id'] }}">{{ $user["name"] }} 
                                        </option>
                                  @endforeach
                             @endif
                    </select>
                </div>
```